# Bootstrap modal when activated inside tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Wanted to see if anyone could help me. I have an edit button that sits inside a table which sits inside bootstrap tabs. When I click the edit link to display modal window it doesnt work. However, when I move the same edit link outside of the tabs, it works like a charm. I think it has something to do with the way bootstrap utilizes jQuery to work the tabs. I'm a jQuery beginner so don't have enough knowledge to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated

Link to invoke modal

```
 <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" class="editToDo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editToDoModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></li>
```

Modal Code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editToDoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editToDoModal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="editToDoModalLabel">Edit To Do Item</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action='{{url("/todo/")}}' class="editFormTodoModal" >
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PATCH'>
                <input type='hidden' name='event_id' value="{{$event->id}}">


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Task:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="">
                    {{--<textarea class="form-control description auto_grow" name="description" id="to_do_description"></textarea>--}}
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the tabs html

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li class="active"><a href="#tasks" data-toggle="tab">Tasks</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="#related_files" data-toggle="tab">Related Files</a></li>
         <li class=""><a href="#event_staff" data-toggle="tab">Event Staff</a></li>
                                            </ul>
```

And the code for the actual tabs

 `<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tasks">
          There is a lot more code but the edit link sits here inside a table
      </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Could you provide the JS/HTML code that you're using?

Comment: just posted an edit with the code. this should automatically invoke a bootstrap modal since all of the jquery is already part of bootstrap framework

Comment: What's the code of your tab elements? Also, `a` elements don't need a `data-target`, you should move the `#editToDoModal` to the `href` attribute.